# Why the regex is not working?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression **^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$** for a java pattern matches and I don't know why is not working. 
I need to accept numbers whit decimal point like this **[+-]123 and [+-]123.123** but it accept [+-]**123.123.123** to.  What I have done bad?

This is the method that check if my number is correct or not

```
 public void addPoint(){

    String pattern = "^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$";
    if(display.getText().matches(pattern)){
        display.setText(display.getText()+".");
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }

 }
```

Comment: your regex `"^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$"` seems good .. http://regex101.com/r/rZ8bG0/3

Comment: Maybe I have done something wrong in my java code.                String pattern = "^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$";
if(display.getText().matches(pattern) do code

Comment: it would be better if you post the code.

Comment: @Avinash Raj I have added the code.

Comment: `^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$` will not match `123.123.123`

Comment: Please provide a test case that shows the problem. Your code doesn't do as you tell us it does.

Comment: I think I know why. I wanted to add just a point to construct a number for a calculator and when i check for 123.123.123 will still be good becouse the test will be after that :)

Comment: This ^[-+]?\\d+\\.{0}\\d+$ now working for me. Thank for your help anyway!!!

Comment: Your last pattern should be the same as `^[-+]?\\d{2,}$`, i.e. matches two or more digits without a decimal point.  `"\\.{0}"` says "match zero occurrences of a period" so it should not have an effect on the regex.

Comment: @SiminaAlin your code should be [`^[-+]?\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d+$`](http://regex101.com/r/xZ9aQ0/1)

Comment: There is no need to add `^` and `$` for `matches` because it looks for whole string match, Make sure there are no treadling and leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "^([-+])?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$";
    String s1 = "+123";
    String s2 = "-123.123";
    String s3 = "-123.123.123";
    System.out.println(s1.matches(pattern));//true
    System.out.println(s2.matches(pattern));//true
    System.out.println(s3.matches(pattern));//false
    //the regex works,there is something wrong in other place
```

Comment: Yes, the regex is good, but I have found an error in my java code. I tought that is something wrong whit the regex.